# Why does a trigger cause a NullReferenceException in style A, but works perfectly in style B (based on style A)?

Tags: xaml, triggers, styles, nullreferenceexception

I have a basis style, and a handfull of styles based on that one. they all use some (same) triggers, which works well - except for one single trigger. This specific one works well only in the derived styles.

Trying to move this trigger into the basic style directly causes a NullReferenceException in Visual Studio Designer. Can anyone tell me why (and how to make it work)?

```
        <Style x:Key="CalendarCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSize9}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF515151"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="MouseDown_Click" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ColorCalendarForegroundDisabled}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ColorCalendarBackgroundDisabled}" />
                </DataTrigger>
<!-- the following trigger HERE causes a  NullReferenceException -->
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualsConverter}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UniformGrid}}"  Path="Tag" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ColorCalendarForegroundSelected}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ColorCalendarBackgroundSelected}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="CalendarCellStyleMonth" BasedOn="{StaticResource CalendarCellStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource MonthNameConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSize12}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
<!-- the very same trigger code HERE works properly ... -->
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualsConverter}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UniformGrid}}"  Path="Tag" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ColorCalendarForegroundSelected}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ColorCalendarBackgroundSelected}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="CalendarCellStyleDay" BasedOn="{StaticResource CalendarCellStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
<!-- ... as well as here too (and so on) -->
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualsConverter}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UniformGrid}}"  Path="Tag" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ColorCalendarForegroundSelected}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ColorCalendarBackgroundSelected}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Unfortunately the stack trace doesn't really give any clue:

> bei DataTest.EqualsConverter.Convert(Object[] values, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
>     bei System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.TransferValue()
>     bei System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.Transfer()
>     bei System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.UpdateTarget(Boolean includeInnerBindings)
>     bei System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
>     bei System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
>     bei MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
>     bei MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
>     bei MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>     bei System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
>     bei System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
>     bei System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved; it was just because of the cut&paste process itself.

After I copied the code snipet into an external text editor, and from **there** again back into the base style, the Exceptions were gone.

I think it's a bug in Visual Studio itself, as originally (I forgot to mention) even rebuilding the complete project wasn't solving the problem.

Sorry.